# Condition inside case statement - SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use conditions inside case statement:

```
    select * from tbl
        where case when expr then
        (
         (x=@_megacity and state_group in (select * from temp_state_megacity)) OR
         (x=@_10lac and state_group in (select * from temp_state_10lac)) OR
         (x=@_below10 and state_group in (select * from temp_state_below10)) OR
         (x=@_rural and state_group in (select * from temp_state_rural))
        ) else true end
```

Error - Incorrect syntax

Comment: `CASE` doesn't work like `if` in a procedural language. It just return an atomic value.

Comment: Ok. so, what is the alternative for this problem?

Comment: Select into temporary table and then use that to filter or make specialized queries

Comment: Can you add sample records for your tables, and the output you would expect that sample to return.  We can use this information to help you refactor your statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `WHERE` clause you use `AND` , `OR` and `NOT` to combine expressions:

```
select * from tbl
    where NOT <expression> OR
    (
     (x=@_megacity and state_group in (select * from temp_state_megacity)) OR
     (x=@_10lac and state_group in (select * from temp_state_10lac)) OR
     (x=@_below10 and state_group in (select * from temp_state_below10)) OR
     (x=@_rural and state_group in (select * from temp_state_rural))
    );
```